# PHP Phalcon. Use postgres nextval(sequence) in model

Tags: php, postgresql, phalcon

I have a table in Postgres with DDL like this one:

```
CREATE TABLE robots(
    robot_id INTEGER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT robot_id_pkey PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT
);
```

I know I can insert a record with following SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO robots (robot_id, name) VALUES (nextval('robots_seq'), 'WALL-E');
```

I need to make CRUD operations in Phalcon for this table. Also I want to use ORM features.
So I do:

```
$robot = new Robots();
$robot->setRobotId(new \Phalcon\Db\RawValue("nextval('robots_seq')"));
$robot->setName('WALL-E');
$robot->save();
```

And get the following exception:

```
Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation:
7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: 'nextval('robots_seq')';
```

Is there any way to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1):

To tell Phalcon what is name of your model sequence use function getSequenceName:

```
public function getSequenceName() {
    return 'category_id_seq';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Phalcon assumes that your models with serial (auto increment) columns will have a sequence named *[table_name]*_*[column_name]*_seq.

In your case, in order to make Phalcon take care of handling auto increment columns you should have a sequence named **robots_robot_id_seq** instead of **robots_seq** for the column *robot_id* (which I'd call just "id", by the way).

This way you do not have to worry about setting the id when creating an object and after saving Phalcon will fill that field automatically for you:

```
CREATE TABLE robots(
robot_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
name TEXT
);

$robot = new Robots();
$robot->setName('WALL-E');
$robot->save();
$robot->getRobotId(); // Should return last "nextval()" sequence
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I can not change DDL structure of `robots` table, since I have a hot table for `robots`, let's call it `robots_hot` and in this table I'm using `serial` primary column and the sequence `robots_seq` for it. I insert rows in it with Phalcon ORM, it's all good; then, when some event arrives, I copy all rows from `robots_hot` to `robots`. But sometimes, I have to insert a row directly in `robots` bypassing `robots_hot`. That's the issue. Temporary solved it with using raw sql query.